# How does salt and pepper noise occurs in an image

Tags: image-processing

How does salt & pepper noise occur? And, what are some techniques to remove it?

Comment: One possible cause would be high-amplitude intermittent electrical interference, affecting either the analogue or digitised signal.  For example, arcing on electrical contacts.

Answer (score 6):

Salt-and-pepper noise is a form of noise sometimes seen on images. It presents itself as sparsely occurring white and black pixels.

In another words ( in the sense of pixels), salt and pepper noise means that are high frequencies, so for salt noise the values of this noise type is high `(255 ... 200)`, and for the pepper noise the values of this noise type is low `(5 ... 0)`.

To salt noise there are good filters like harmonic mean filters
to salt and pepper noise.

$$
   \hat{f}(x,y) = \frac{mn}{\sum_{(s,t) \in S_{xy}}\frac{1}{g(s,t)} }
   $$

There are the contra harmonic filter that depends of a $Q$ argument, e.g., for salt noise $Q$ should be negative and for pepper Q should be positive.

$$
   \hat{f}(x,y) = \frac{\sum_{(s,t) \in S_{xy}}g(s,t)^{Q+1}}{{\tiny\sum_{(s,t) \in S_{xy}}}g(s,t)^{Q} }
   $$

Another aproach is the order statistics filters, e.g., $\operatorname{max}$
 filter are good for pepper noise, and $\operatorname{min}$ filter are good for salt noise.

$$ \hat{f}(x,y) = \operatorname{max}_{(s,t)\in S_{xy}}{g(s,t)}$$
$$ \hat{f}(x,y) = \operatorname{min}_{(s,t)\in S_{xy}}{g(s,t)} $$

And another one is alpha trimmed filter that also are a order statistics filter type.

$$ \hat{f}(x,y) = \frac{1}{mn-d}\sum_{(s,t) \in S_{x,y}} g_r(s,t)$$

Beside this there are Adaptive Mean Filter.

Comment: For completion sake, when both salt and pepper noise are present, median filter is good.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_noise#Salt-and-pepper_noise), salt-and-pepper noise is generated by errors during analog to digital conversion or data transfer. It can be corrected with median filtering.

Comment: A good answer should do more than quote a couple of sentences from Wikipedia...

Comment: A good question should ask for more than a couple of sentences from Wikipedia...

Comment: I agree; that's what the downvote button is for. Personally, I prefer to give links or pointers to the answer as a comment.